# Java JFrame will not update inputted text

Tags: java, string, swing, math, user-input

I am pretty new to java when compared to python, having only really using it for about 5 months, and up until 2 months ago only using it for android development. I want to learn more about java especially since I basically just skipped strait to the android dev stuff, and learned only what I needed for whatever project I was working on in that. To help me learn, I decided to learn to make a GUI with swing and a simple calculator. I did it in an hour or two, not counting learning swing, and for a very first non-android java program I'm pretty happy with it

the problem i'm having tho, is that when you input 2 numbers, click a button to perform a calculation, then change the numbers and do it again, the program will still use the original numbers, despite them no longer being there

It does read when there are no numbers or a missing number in the input, but just won't use the new numbers for any calculations.

here is the entire program, sorry for the poorly named variables and generally bad code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class calc implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel num1;
    private JLabel num2;
    private JLabel lans;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton add;
    private JButton sub;
    private JButton mult;
    private JButton div;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField tnum1;
    private JTextField tnum2;

    public calc() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);

        num1 = new JLabel("1st Number");
        num1.setBounds(20, 20, 80, 25);
        panel.add(num1);

        num2 = new JLabel("2nd Number");
        num2.setBounds(20, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(num2);

        tnum1 = new JTextField();
        tnum1.setBounds(100, 20, 80, 25);
        panel.add(tnum1);

        tnum2 = new JTextField();
        tnum2.setBounds(100, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(tnum2);

        add = new JButton("+");
        add.setBounds(20, 100, 50, 40);
        add.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(add);

        sub = new JButton("-");
        sub.setBounds(80, 100, 50, 40);
        sub.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(sub);

        mult = new JButton("×");
        mult.setBounds(140, 100, 50, 40);
        mult.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(mult);

        div = new JButton("÷");
        div.setBounds(200, 100, 50, 40);
        div.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(div);

        lans = new JLabel("");
        lans.setBounds(120, 150, 150, 25);
        panel.add(lans);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new calc();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!tnum1.getText().isEmpty() && !tnum2.getText().isEmpty()) {
            String snum1 = tnum1.getText();
            String snum2 = tnum1.getText();
            Double fnum1 = Double.valueOf(snum1);
            Double fnum2 = Double.valueOf(snum2);

            if (e.getSource() == add) {
                Double nans = fnum1 + fnum2;
                lans.setText(String.valueOf(nans));

            } else if (e.getSource() == sub) {
                Double nans = fnum1 - fnum2;
                lans.setText(String.valueOf(nans));

            } else if (e.getSource() == mult) {
                Double nans = fnum1 * fnum2;
                lans.setText(String.valueOf(nans));

            } else if (e.getSource() == div) {
                Double nans = fnum1 / fnum2;
                lans.setText(String.valueOf(nans));
            }

        } else if (!tnum1.getText().isEmpty()) {
            lans.setText("No number 2");

        } else if (!tnum2.getText().isEmpty()) {
            lans.setText("No number 1");

        } else {
            lans.setText("enter 2 numbers");
        }
    }
}
```

yea I know the variables are a bit confusing, but i'm not super familiar with naming conventions yet and i figured since this was a program that I was only using to learn a few select things I didn't really need to use them, especially since I was not planning on actually posting this anywhere.

Edit: im blind, took the first number twice instead of taking both numbers

Comment: *String snum2 = tnum1.getText();* should be *String snum2 = tnum2.getText();*

Answer (score 0):

so I think I found your problem. The only thing you need to change is this.

```
int snum1 = Integer.parseInt(tnum1.getText());
int snum2 = Integer.parseInt(tnum2.getText());
```

This portion should go in the actionPerformed. I think the only problem you had was that you used the first variable two times and not the first and the second to do your math.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged your code because I wanted to explain a few principles about Swing development.

Here's the GUI I created.

[image: Calculator GUI]

1. All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method call ensures that all Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. Absolute positioning of Swing components is painful to do and not conducive to the various operating systems and monitor resolutions that people use.  I used a [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for the main `JPanel` and a [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) for the button `JPanel`.  Sure, the code looks more complicated.  But I didn't have to calculate any component size or location.  The [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) do this for me.
3. I added a couple of `JFrame` methods to give the GUI a title and position it on the screen according to the operating system.
4. I broke up the GUI creation code into methods, so I could focus on one part of the GUI at a time.

Here's the code.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class SimpleCalculatorGUI implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel lans;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton add;
    private JButton sub;
    private JButton mult;
    private JButton div;
    private JTextField tnum1;
    private JTextField tnum2;

    public SimpleCalculatorGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel());
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
           panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
           panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
           
           GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
           gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
           gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
           gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
           gbc.gridx = 0;
           gbc.gridy = 0;
           gbc.weightx = 1d;

           JLabel num1 = new JLabel("1st Number");
           panel.add(num1, gbc);

           gbc.gridx++;
           tnum1 = new JTextField(10);
           panel.add(tnum1, gbc);
           
           gbc.gridx = 0;
           gbc.gridy++;
           JLabel num2 = new JLabel("2nd Number");
           panel.add(num2, gbc);

           gbc.gridx++;
           tnum2 = new JTextField(10);
           panel.add(tnum2, gbc);
           
           gbc.gridx = 0;
           gbc.gridy++;
           gbc.gridwidth = 2;
           panel.add(createButtonPanel(), gbc);

           gbc.gridy++;
           lans = new JLabel(" ");
           lans.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
           panel.add(lans, gbc);
           
           return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        
         add = new JButton("+");
         add.addActionListener(this);
         panel.add(add);

         sub = new JButton("-");
         sub.addActionListener(this);
         panel.add(sub);

         mult = new JButton("×");
         mult.addActionListener(this);
         panel.add(mult);

         div = new JButton("÷");
         div.addActionListener(this);
         panel.add(div);
         
         return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SimpleCalculatorGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!tnum1.getText().isEmpty() 
                && !tnum2.getText().isEmpty()) {
            String snum1 = tnum1.getText();
            String snum2 = tnum2.getText();
            Double fnum1 = Double.valueOf(snum1);
            Double fnum2 = Double.valueOf(snum2);

            if (e.getSource() == add) {
                Double nans = fnum1 + fnum2;
                lans.setText(String.valueOf(nans));

            } else if (e.getSource() == sub) {
                Double nans = fnum1 - fnum2;
                lans.setText(String.valueOf(nans));

            } else if (e.getSource() == mult) {
                Double nans = fnum1 * fnum2;
                lans.setText(String.valueOf(nans));

            } else if (e.getSource() == div) {
                Double nans = fnum1 / fnum2;
                lans.setText(String.valueOf(nans));
            }

        } else if (!tnum1.getText().isEmpty()) {
            lans.setText("No number 2");

        } else if (!tnum2.getText().isEmpty()) {
            lans.setText("No number 1");

        } else {
            lans.setText("Enter 2 numbers");
        }
    
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is that you used `tnum1.getText()` tow times instead of `tnum2.getText()`

you just need to change the third line in `actionPerformed(e)` to `String snum2 = tnum2.getText();` and it will work